# Firefox SDK using a sidebar instead of a panel

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk, sidebar

how can I do a complete replacement for my Firefox-SDK Panel, using a sidebar to show my html instead?
I couldn't find any official module :(
I just wanna show a sidebar with the same functions a panel offers.

Edit:
Got an example screenshot from firebug, want the same sidebar look for my add on :)
[image]

Does anyone know how to add sth. like an onShow event (as known from the Panel), to call a function. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: According to [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Creating_a_Firefox_sidebar) the sidebar is deprecated, but there's a [sample on GitHub of how to do it with an extension](https://github.com/kyoshino/simple-sidebar)

Comment: The sidebar itself is not deprecated, only the API that permit to a remote web page to create a sidebar it is. It means, from an extension, it's perfectly fine create a sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new [Sidebar API](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/doc/module-source/sdk/ui.md) in the Add-on SDK. Although they're still experimental, you can start to play with them.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the sidebar.js file is always missing in my code (getting an exception after cfx run), the import was correctly. I found this third party api https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/25177/

but i does not work the way, i want it to :)

Comment: It's a new API so you need to checkout the master branch of add-on sdk, or use a Firefox version where is landed – in Nightly, for sure. I don't know if it's in Beta or Aurora too.

Comment: Hey Zero, always got the same Problem.
This is my code: 

var Sidebar = require("sdk/ui").Sidebar;

var sidebarPanel = Sidebar({
    id: 'a-new-sidebar',
    title: 'A New Sidebar',
//    icon: './icon.png',
    url: data.url("panel.html"),
  });
I dont know what i am doing wrong, always got the same exception.

Error: Module `sdk/ui` is not found at resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/ui.js

I downloaded the latest master branch and used it :(

Comment: How do you run your code? You have to use the override option, so, for example: `cfx run -o`; in case you got some other error, try using the nightly. An example of cmd line on OS X: `cfx run -b /Applications/FirefoxNightly.app -o`